# Extracting HTML from javascript protected website

Tags: java

A website www.kissanime.to has a "Is javascript enabled on your browser" protection so when you want to read the html content of the website you have to have a browser with javascript enabled so using this code won't work:

```
   URL kissanime = new URL("http://www.kissanime.to/");
    URLConnection ks = kissanime.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(ks.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
```

And after a while of researching I found Selenium it's a browser library emulator:

```
        HtmlUnitDriver html = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    String URL="https://www.kissanime.to/";
    html.get(URL);
    String pageSource=html.getPageSource();
    System.out.println(pageSource);
```

And that works but isn't there a better way to do this like with Jsoup and Rhino libraries where you will make an initial connection with jsoup and then you will add rhino to make it seem that you have javascript or better yet only Jsoup and adding some cookies to bypass the protection.

Comment: I wouldn't call that "protection". They are just giving you a warning saying their site won't work unless you enable Javascript

Comment: that's not a protection it's a kind of warning, anyway, i used to do it that way too.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is a pretty heavyweight solution for such a simple use case. If You need a basic engine emulating a real browser with javascript enabled then HtmlUnit (http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) is what you are looking for.

Here is a code fragment which scrapes data from google.com:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage googlePage = webClient.getPage("http://www.google.com/");
//posibly wait for the javascript to execute
String source = googlePage.asXml()
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it like you but not only that page anyway, you can get the html this way by it's url, also emulate a browser

```
private String conexion(String link) {
        String content = null;
        URLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = new URL(link).openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
            scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
            content = scanner.next();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡¡Ese capitulo no Existe!!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        return content;
    }
```